# how does an optical telescope work?

Tags: optics, waves, reflection, telescopes

I know that an optical telescope uses mirrors and light waves, but I still don't understand how it works. Could you please tell me?
(please don't make the answer too complex or too  simple.)

Comment: That's like asking water not to be wet.

Comment: A telescope alters the incoming light rays from a distant object using either mirrors or glass lenses so as to "trick" the eye of the observer looking through the telescope's eyepiece that the object is much closer (and therefore apparently much larger) than it really is.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Unfortunately, your comment contains a common misconception, namely that telescopes significantly magnify objects (unless you're talking about old-timey spyglasses, but I'm going to assume the OP is talking about telescopes built in the last century). Typically, most optical observatories have magnifications below 10x. Instead, telescopes are useful because they collect a bunch of light into the eyepiece, allowing one to see much fainter objects (not necessarily smaller or more distant) than can be seen by the eye.

Comment: While I haven't time to write a descent answer, I'll note that this is easier to follow in terms of *ray optics* rather than *wave optics*. That is, for most questions involving lenses and mirrors it is easier to work on the assumption that "light moves in straight lines" rather than dealing with the complexity of waves. But you'll need to start by understanding single focusing devices (lens and mirrors), then move on to compound systems.

Answer (score 2):

If you view for instance the moon. Its two opposite edges will make an angle at your eye. The telescope increases that angle thus magnifying. There is a long focal length lens the objective that produces the image. The eye-piece enlarges that image just as a reading glass would. Now the larger the focal length of the objective lens the larger will be the image formed by it. Also smaller the focal length of the eye-piece the large will be the image you would see. The magnification is given by the ratio of two focal lengths objective/eye-piece.